# Selecting TextCell by code doesn't highlight row

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When I click a TextCell in a ListView, the row is highlighted.

However, when I programatically select a row / a TextCell, the row isn't highlighted.

Therefore it isn't possible to indicate to the user which value in a ListView is currently selected unless he changes the selection by tapping a row.

Is that a bug or a missing feature, or how could I achieve the highlighting via code?

Sample code is attached below.

```cs
using MyApp.Model;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class IntSelector : ContentPage
    {
        private ListView m_ListView;

        public IntSelector(int uSelectedInt)
        {
            DataTemplate nTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(TextCell));

            // We can set data bindings to our supplied objects.
            nTemplate.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, "String");
            nTemplate.SetBinding(TextCell.DetailProperty, "Int");

            List<clsStringInt> nList = new List<clsStringInt>();

            clsStringInt nItem1 = new clsStringInt { String = "German", Int = 1031 };
            clsStringInt nItem2 = new clsStringInt { String = "English", Int = 1033 };
            clsStringInt nItem3 = new clsStringInt { String = "Spanish", Int = 1034 };

            nList.Add(nItem1);
            nList.Add(nItem2);
            nList.Add(nItem3);

            m_ListView = new ListView();
            m_ListView.ItemTemplate = nTemplate;
            m_ListView.ItemsSource = nList;

            m_ListView.ItemSelected += this.OnSelection;

            m_ListView.SelectedItem = nItem2;//this triggers the "OnSelection" event, so it works
            nItem2.String = "->> " + nItem2.String; //the item's new string is display in the ListView, so that works as well
            //what DOESN'T work is the highliting

            this.Content = m_ListView;
        }

        void OnSelection(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.SelectedItem == null)
            {
                return; //ItemSelected is called on deselection, which results in SelectedItem being set to null
            }

            clsStringInt n = (clsStringInt)e.SelectedItem;
            string sSelectedIntAsString = n.Int.ToString();

            DisplayAlert("Item Selected", sSelectedIntAsString, "Ok");
        }

    }
}

namespace MyApp.Model
{
    public class clsStringInt
    {
        public string String { get; set; }
        public int Int { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Forms are you using and is there any .xaml code for your page because I've yet to recreate it with your code where it didn't have the row highlighted.

Comment: No, it's plain C#, no XAML required. Xamarin.Forms 2.4.0.74863

Comment: @Nick I've updated to 2.5.0.91635 now, same behaviour.

Comment: Are you running it on a device or in the simulator

Comment: Running it in the UWP simulator.

Comment: Okay that explains it I only ran it on Android and iOS not UWP. My guess is it's a UWP Forms bug since it in general seems way behind its mobile counterparts but I'll check it on Windows real quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you are testing on a UWP Forms app which this appears to be a bug specifically on that platform seeing how it works fine on Android and iOS.

I was able to work around this by setting the selected item in `OnAppearing` instead of in the Page constructor to get it to highlight.

Comment: Oh man, I would have never been able to figure out this workaround by myself. Or even recognize what the culprit was. You really saved me. Thank you so much.

Comment: I would like to add that your solution only works for me when I use "_lv.SelectedItem = ..." after I said "this.Content = _lv;". Perhaps because the ".Content =" causes a focus problem which then clears the visible selection?

Comment: You're creating your ListView before it's actually added to the Content of the page on screen so if you moved all that logic into OnAppearing and not just SelectedItem= I could see having to move setting the SelectedItem until after to get it working.